# Upgrading from Cordova 1.5 to 2.0.0

Tags: cordova

Hi I'm having trouble upgrading my version of Cordova to 2.0.0 and I was wondering if anyone could give me some advice.  I ran the installer and from what I read that should have upgraded the version that I had previously installed but the fills are all still called Cordova1.5.

Am I missing some part of the process?

Thanks

**EDIT**

As it turns out it did install correctly but Cordova 2.0 does not replace the older versions in the same way as upgrading before did.  Instead it is necessary to create new Cordova 2.0 projects through their new command line tools. More information available [here](http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2012/07/20/improvements-in-cordova-2-0-0-for-ios/)

Comment: Hi! Is it for Android or iOS? What do you mean by "still called Cordova 1.5"?. Could you provide more details?

Comment: Hi Littm. Sorry I should have said, it's for iOS.  Basically I installed the new version as per these instructions http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_upgrading_ios_index.md.html and now have the new framework installed in the frameworks folder but I can't get a new Cordova 2.0 project in xCode.  It just has "pre 2.0" projects.

Comment: Sorry that is the link to the upgrading instructions.  That is where my other problem lies.  I tried to do this but have loads of errors now.

Comment: For my part I simply install the Cordova 2.0.0 installation package. I did not follow the upgrading process, and for no particular reason it worked like a charm :S... You may try to install the new version of Cordova through the installation package?

Comment: Yes I tried that too.  No sign of it in the frameworks folder and when I created a project through terminal but I got errors straight away. It's weird.  I think I'll uninstall all versions of phonegap and start again.

Comment: :O... oh... which errors do you get through the terminal?

Comment: I eventually got it to work.  Turns out I had missed a step.  Thanks for your help though. Much appreciated. :)